# Java Regex: Check in specific order

Tags: java, regex

I have the following array of regular expressions:

```
String[] array = new String[] { 
  "(car)|(truck)|(bus)|(van)", //4) transportation
  "(w)|(x)|(y)|(z)", //1) options
    "1|2|3|4", //2) numbers
    "(red)|(blue)|(green)|(pink)|(yellow)" //3) color
};
```

and I have the following string:

```
String s= "1 blue w truck";
```

I am trying to iterate over this string to see if any of the words in the string match any of the regular expressions in the array. This is what I am doing:

```
for(int i=0; i<array.length;i++){
      Pattern word = Pattern.compile(array[i]);
      Matcher match = word.matcher(s);
      while(match.find() ){
        System.out.println(String.format(" Using regex %d:  %s",i,match.group()));
      }
    }
```

This gives the following output:

```
Using regex 0:  truck
Using regex 1:  w
Using regex 2:  1
Using regex 3:  blue
```

But I want the following to be the output:

```
Using regex 2:  1
Using regex 3:  blue
Using regex 1:  w
Using regex 0:  truck
```

I want the words in the strings to stay in the same order without changing the order of the regular expressions in the array.

Comment: You will need to loop on parts of the string instead then. This might be a bit less efficient, as you will then also need to loop through each of the regexes until you hit a match also.

Comment: Would it be a valid solution for you to combine the pattern array to one regular expression? Or is the pattern array a must have?

Comment: @Alexander I can't do that. I have to distinguish which thing I found in the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using a pojo that will contain the relevant information of your matches (arbitrarily called `MatchInfo` here), and a `TreeSet` ordering your matches by the required criterion (the index of the match within the given `String`).

```
// your patterns
String[] array = new String[] { 
    "(car)|(truck)|(bus)|(van)", // 4) // transportation
    "(w)|(x)|(y)|(z)", // 1) options
    "1|2|3|4", // 2) numbers
    "(red)|(blue)|(green)|(pink)|(yellow)" // 3) color
};
// your input
String s = "1 blue w truck";

// the definition of the relevant information you want to keep on matches
class MatchInfo implements Comparable<MatchInfo>{
    int index;
    Integer start;
    String match;
    MatchInfo(int index, int start, String match) {
        this.index = index;
        this.start = start;
        this.match = match;
    }
    @Override
    // comparing start index of the match within original string
    public int compareTo(MatchInfo o) {
        return start.compareTo(o.start);
    };
}
// orders unique elements by natural ordering, as defined by Comparable 
// implementation
Set<MatchInfo> groups = new TreeSet<>();

// your original iteration
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    Pattern word = Pattern.compile(array[i]);
    Matcher match = word.matcher(s);
    while (match.find()) {
        // adding new "MatchInfo" to the set
        groups.add(new MatchInfo(i, match.start(), match.group()));
    }
}

// iterating and printing the info
for (MatchInfo m: groups) {
    System.out.printf("Using regex %d: %s%n", m.index, m.match);
}
```

**Output**

```
Using regex 2: 1
Using regex 3: blue
Using regex 1: w
Using regex 0: truck
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to loop on parts of the string instead. This might be a bit less efficient, as you will then also need to loop through each of the regexes until you hit a match also.

Something like the following should help:

```
String[] parts = s.split(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    for (int r; r < array.length; r++) {
        Pattern word = Pattern.compile(array[i]);
        Matcher match = word.matcher(s);
        if (match.find()) {
            // print out stuff
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As @dimplex pointed out in their answer, I am unnecessarily recompiling the patterns in the array on each iteration. An optimization would involve precompiling all of the patterns, as their answer demonstrates.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling the pattern on each iteration is not necessary.

```
        Pattern[] array = new Pattern[] { 
              Pattern.compile("^((car)|(truck)|(bus)|(van))"), //4) transportation
              Pattern.compile("^((w)|(x)|(y)|(z))"), //1) options
              Pattern.compile("^(1|2|3|4)"), //2) numbers
              Pattern.compile("^((red)|(blue)|(green)|(pink)|(yellow))") //3) color
            };
    String s= "1 blue w truck";

    while(s.length() > 0) {
        for(int i=0; i<array.length;i++){
          Matcher match = array[i].matcher(s);
          if(match.find()) {
              String substr = match.group();
              System.out.println(String.format(" Using regex %d:  %s",i, substr));
              s = s.substring(substr.length()).trim();
          }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be using a more complex regular expression and use **capturing groups**. I added a little extra to provide you a type string by using **named capturing groups** in the regular expression. If you don't like it you may use *groupCount()* and *group(i)* iteration to return the matched group index.

```
    public static void main() {
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<transportation>(?:car)|(?:truck)|(?:bus)|(?:van))|(?<options>[wxyz])|(?<numbers>[1-4])|(?<color>(?:red)|(?:blue)|(?:green)|(?:pink)|(?:yellow))");

      String s = "1 blue w truck";

      Matcher match = pattern.matcher(s);
      while(match.find()) {
        printGroupMatch(match, "transportation");
        printGroupMatch(match, "options");
        printGroupMatch(match, "numbers");
        printGroupMatch(match, "color");
      }
    }

    private static void printGroupMatch(Matcher match, String gName) {
      String groupValue = match.group(gName);
      if(groupValue != null){
        System.out.println(String.format(" Using regex %s:  %s", gName, groupValue));
    }
  }
```

This will return you something like this:

```
 Using regex numbers:  1
 Using regex color:  blue
 Using regex options:  w
 Using regex transportation:  truck
```